# grub error, cannot boot win 7 after trying to install win 8

Tags: grub2, windows-8

I tried installing win 8 and had to cancel the setup at a point. And now when I start my pc an error comes up like:

```
Find --set_root- --ignore floppies-.../bootmgr
Error 15: file not found
Press any key to continue...
```

And when I press a key it goes to the red grub4dos menu, and there are a lot of options there, but I have no idea what to do. I have win 7 installed but don't know how to boot it. I am totally new to grub. Please help me solve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a wiki page that briefly explains how to solve the problem:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Please, leave a comment if you need more help.

Comment: thanks for the reply..but now the problem is something else.I went through some other sites where it explained that I can do something like:

Comment: thanks for the reply..but now the problem is something else.I went through some other sites where it explained that I can do something like:rootnoverify(hd0,0) makeactive boot. Now the problem is that when I boot an error shows up like''bootmgr is missing.  Press ctrl+alt+delete to reboot..I think I am in serious trouble now,please help

Comment: I suggest you to close this question and open a new one, adding detailed information about what has happened, what you did and linking the guides you have followed.